SNAP STORE does not display files when I select a Proton VPN server. How can I fix that?
I run Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on an HP Elitebook 8460P with 8GB RAM and 250GB HDD storage space.
I use Proton VPN and login after Ubuntu boots to my desktop.
(I have the Kill switch set to the Advanced setting so that my WIFI will not connect to the internet if the VPN is not running or is disconnected.)
Immediately afterward the Livepatch shield symbol displays a red exclamation point,
and an error message that says error loading updates.
When I check the SNAP STORE from the ~Ubuntu Software~  "installed" list, it's blank!
Once I have been on-line for 10-20 minutes, the Livepatch shield symbol displays a green checkmark...
BUT I am still unable to see a list of my "installed" apps or see a list of apps that I can "Explore".
Is the problem seeing these files listed/available because "Ubuntu Pro" is enabled through the Software & Updates app that comes with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?
I hope this is enough info to help answer my questions.
Thank you
Will Black
